# Jenkins CI - Promote Corresponding Downstream Jobs

Tags: jenkins, promoted-builds

I am currently using the Promoted Builds Plugin to promote jobs into QA, Test, Production, etc. This plugin is really great for promoting a single job. However I am looking for a way to promote the parent job and have that job promote the rest of the downstream jobs with the corresponding build.

Here is an example. Lets say I have 3 jobs that are all triggered from an upstream job:

- Job 1 - Build 200 - Parent job kicks off job 2 upon successful build
- Job 2 - Build 400 - Job 2 kicks off job 3 upon successful build
- Job 3 - Build 300 - Job 3 builds after job 2 is successful

After this is done I want to be able to promote job 1 build 200 and have that job also promote job2 build 400 and job 3 build 300 since these are the artifacts that were built together in the downstream relationship.

This can be easily done by actually building the jobs and automatically promoting them, but I do not want to build as the artifacts have already been created.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Good question. I am struggling with this too. Another thing is when I delete a parent job, I'd like that the downstream jobs are deleted as well.

Comment: Hey Vezenkov I will try to post what I ended up doing tonight. Hopefully it will help... Stay tuned!